# How do you know the size of a 7zip compressed file?

Tags: windows-7, compression, zip

With an archive file, I can only ever find the size of the file before compression, its original size, which I know.

What about the size of the new, smaller compressed size?

Comment: David, thanks for the edit, much in need after I got a bit upset and started going on, my ignorance frustrates me and then the toys can start to come out of the pram. Also, I much appreciate your time for the subsequent answer, 7zip compression rates are the best, apparently? ease of use and support to facilitate this must rank among the worst, I'd say but that's no fault of yours, obviously. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 4):

#### How to I find the compressed sizes of files in a 7zip archive?

You can use the command line version of 7zip which is `7z`, with the `l` (list) option:

```
7z l archive.zip
```

Example:

```
F:\test>c:\apps\7-zip\7z l wscc.zip

7-Zip [64] 9.38 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2014 Igor Pavlov  2015-01-03

Listing archive: wscc.zip

--
Path = wscc.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 1549613

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2015-07-20 16:33:04 ....A      3569152      1547123  wscc.exe
2015-01-05 18:42:28 ....A         2640         1283  wscc.license.txt
2015-02-25 21:50:48 ....A         1897          879  wscc.readme.txt
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2015-07-20 16:33:04            3573689      1549285  3 files

Kernel  Time =     0.109 =   29%
User    Time =     0.000 =    0%
Process Time =     0.109 =   29%    Virtual  Memory =      4 MB
Global  Time =     0.366 =  100%    Physical Memory =      7 MB
```

#### Further reading

- [7zip Command Line Syntax](http://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm)
- [7zip Command Line Switches](http://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/index.htm)
- [7zip Command Line Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)

Comment: You can get the same information in the GUI under the "Packed Size" column (select View > Details or Ctrl+4). Or hit the big `i` "Info" button on the toolbar (or Alt+Enter) for more information and a summary when no files are selected.